# AC2 Declaring Hexadecimals

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

In flash AC2, I am declaring this variable with global var

```
_global.t1_stage.color = 0x999999;
```

When I do

```
trace(_global.t1_stage.color)
```

It prints, but it tells me that this is undefined.
help?
I want to add it to this

```
var colorful2 = new Color("_root.StageNew");
colorful2.setRGB(_global.t1_stage.color);
```

But it turns black..

Comment: is your t1_stage object available at the moment you declare variable? is it dynamic (allowed to create properties on execution)?

Comment: The thing is, I want to declare t1_stage as a variable  equal to #999999, so when i try to trace t1_stage variable, it tells me its undefined, and when I use it in the code, it makes the object black. It is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

In ActionScript 2, we use `_global` just when setting a global variable not when using it.

In your case you are trying to use a global `Object` named `t1_stage` with a `color` property, so you can do like this :

```
// create an Object "t1_stage"
_global.t1_stage = {}

        // add the "color" property
        t1_stage['color'] = 0xff0000;   // red

// here we don't need to use "_global"
trace(t1_stage.color);      // gives : 16711680

var colorful2:Color = new Color(_root.StageNew);
    colorful2.setRGB(t1_stage.color);
```

Hope that can help.